# issues while installing scipy

Tags: python-3

I updated the python version to `3.7`. While installing scipy using `sudo apt-get install python-scipy` it says `python-scipy is already the newest version (1.1.0-7).`.
I also need a python package called `wfdb`. While installing it using `pip install wfdb`, it collects `scipy` and builds the wheel.

I get an error at this point.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
Running setup.py clean for scipy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-90c9fl_s/scipy/setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install- 
90c9fl_s/scipy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
clean --all
      cwd: /tmp/pip-install-90c9fl_s/scipy
Complete output (9 lines):

`setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

   - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
   - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                    files that aren't checked into the git repo)

Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must 
(unsupported).

----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed to build scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot 
be installed directly
```

I tried the same procedure for `python2.7`, `wfdb` was successfully installed. I am using **Raspberry Pi 4 Model B** and the OS is **Raspbian**.

I tried a couple of commands like `pip install scipy`, `pip install scipy==1.0.0rc2`. I have upgraded and updated using `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Still getting the same error.

Can I get some help?

Comment: Last [scipy version](https://www.scipy.org/) is `SciPy 1.4.1 released` , try installing with git project : `git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git scipy` following [this link](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/linux.html#generic-instructions)

Comment: Buster already has 3.7 so you need to explain what you have done and why. All the rest of your post is about python2.

Comment: Any progress/luck? I have the same issue.